# recover old Twitter consumer key and secret

Tags: twitter-oauth

Is there any way to put back the old consumer key and secret after it has been reset?  That is return the Twitter application details key and secret to a previous version.

Comment: No, once you reset them they can't be reverted.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of.  Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Once you reset the consumer key/secret you have to deploy the new key or your application will stop working.